# Capture client side logs in server side in angular2

Tags: angular, logging

I have integrated angular2-logger in my application. I am able to print the logger in client side console.

What is the best to way to move loggers from client side to server side?

Answer (score 0):

JSNLog is best way to log to server, documentation is awesome and working fine with angular 2.

http://js.jsnlog.com/Documentation/HowTo/Angular2Logging

Kindly check above url for the same. For this you need a service through which u can post your logs to server. There is also a facility to sent logs in batches so it will reduced traffic to server.

Comment: If possible it's a good idea to take the key parts of what you have linked to and put it in the answer, that way if the URL goes bad we still have the answer :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion, I will keep this in mind and will update the answer accordingly.